# how to generate multiple electricity bills from mysql database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to iterate through this array and display them in a view

Here are my codes that calculates customers electricity bills :

```
public function facturation()
    {
        $data = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('client');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result() as $clients){
        $query_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $date_act = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($query_date));

        $number = round(microtime(true)*100);
        $code = 'FHT-'.$number;

        //recovery of the calculated parameters in the database

               $this->db->select('
                        prise_releve.client_id,
                        index_actif,
                        puissance_max,
                        puissance_souscrit,
                        index_reactif,
                        facteur_u_energie,
                        facteur_u_puissance,
                        date_prise,
                        MONTH(date_prise) as mois_concerne,
                        designation

                ');
              
               $this->db->where('date_prise', $date_act);
               $this->db->where('prise_releve.client_id', $clients->id_client);
               $this->db->from('prise_releve');
               $this->db->join('client','client.id_client = prise_releve.client_id');
               $this->db->join('contrat','client.id_client = contrat.client_id');
               
               $query = $this->db->get();
                 foreach ($query->result() as $row){ 
                   $index_act2 = $row->index_actif;
                   $index_react2 = $row->index_reactif;
                   $date_p2 = $row->date_prise;

                   $fact_ene = $row->facteur_u_energie;
                   $fact_puis = $row->facteur_u_puissance;
                   $p_max = $row->puissance_max;
                   $p_sous = $row->puissance_souscrit; 
                   $clientid = $row->client_id;
                   $client = $row->designation;
                   

                }

                $newdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime ('-1 month' , strtotime($date_act))) ;
                $this->db->select('
                        index_actif,
                        index_reactif,
                        date_prise');

                $this->db->where('date_prise', $newdate);
                $this->db->where('client_id', $clients->id_client);
                $this->db->from('prise_releve');
                $this->db->join('client','client.id_client = prise_releve.client_id');

                $query2 = $this->db->get();
                 foreach ($query2->result() as $row){ 
                   $index_act = $row->index_actif;
                   $index_react = $row->index_reactif;
                   $mois_conc = utf8_encode(ucwords(strftime("%B", strtotime($row->date_prise))));
                   $date_p1 = $row->date_prise; 

                }

                $this->db->select('
                libelle,
                valeur
                ');
        
                $this->db->where('libelle',"FI");
                $this->db->from('parametrage');
                $query3 = $this->db->get();
                 foreach ($query3->result() as $row){ 
                $fact_index = $row->valeur;

                }

                $this->db->select('
                libelle,
                valeur
                ');
        
                $this->db->where('libelle',"CM");
                $this->db->from('parametrage');
                $query4 = $this->db->get();
                 foreach ($query4->result() as $row){ 

                $coef_mult = $row->valeur;
                }


                $this->db->where('libelle',"TVA");
                $this->db->from('parametrage');
                $query4 = $this->db->get();
                 foreach ($query4->result() as $row){ 

                $tva = $row->valeur;
                }

                //Calculate bills 

                $constant = 0.65;

                $p_exp = ($fact_index*$constant*($fact_puis/100)*$coef_mult);
                $e_exp = ($fact_index*($fact_ene/100));

                $e_exp = number_format($e_exp, 5, '.', ',');
                $p_exp = number_format($p_exp, 5, '.', ',');

                $cons_act = (($index_act2-$index_act)*$coef_mult);
                $cons_react = (($index_react2-$index_react)*$coef_mult);

                $cons_act11 = $index_act2-$index_act;
                $cons_react11 = $index_react2-$index_react;

                $cons_act = number_format($cons_act, 2, '.', ',');
                $cons_react = number_format($cons_react, 2, '.', ',');

                $cos_phi= ($cons_act11/(sqrt(($cons_act11*$cons_act11)+($cons_react11*$cons_react11))));
                $cons_phi = number_format($cos_phi, 2, '.', ' ');

            
                if($cons_phi >= 0.95){

                    $pena = 0;

                }elseif($cons_phi>= 0.85 && $cons_phi< 0.95){

                    $pena = (0.5*(0.95-$cons_phi));

                }elseif($cons_phi


                    = 0.60 && $cons_phi< 0.85){

                    $pena = (0.5+1*(0.85-$cons_phi));

                }elseif($cons_phi>= 0.55 && $cons_phi< 0.60){

                    $pena = (0.3+2*(0.60-$cons_phi));

                }elseif($cons_phi>= 0.5 && $cons_phi< 0.55){

                    $pena = (0.4+2.5*(0.55-$cons_phi));

                }else if($cons_phi< 0.50){
                   
                   $pena = (0.5+3*(0.50-$cons_phi));

                }


                if($p_max > 1.05*$p_sous){
         
                     $pf = ($p_max+(0.5*($p_max-$p_sous)));
                  }
                  else if($p_max>= 0.85*$p_sous && $p_max<= 1.05*$p_sous){
                      $pf = $p_max;
                  }

                  else if($p_max< 0.85*$p_sous){

                      $pf = 0.85*$p_sous;
                  }

                  $mnt_redev1 = ($pf*$p_exp);
                  $cons_act1 = (($index_act2-$index_act)*$coef_mult);

                  $mnt_redev = number_format($pf*$p_exp, 2, '.', ',');
                  $mnt_energie1 = ($cons_act11*$e_exp);
                  $mnt_energie = number_format($mnt_energie1*$coef_mult, 2, '.', ',');

                  $mnt_energie2 = $mnt_energie1*$coef_mult;

                  $mnt_energie = number_format($mnt_energie1*$coef_mult, 2, '.', ',');
                
                  $mnt_total = $mnt_redev1+$mnt_energie2;
                  $mnt_total2 = $mnt_redev1+$mnt_energie2;
                  $total_tva = (($mnt_total2*$tva)/100)+$mnt_total2;

                  $data['facture'] = array(    
                    "index_act"=>$index_act,
                    "index_react"=>$index_react,
                    "index_act2"=>$index_act2,
                    "index_react2"=>$index_react2,
                    "fact_ue"=>$fact_ene,
                    "fact_up"=>$fact_puis,
                    "p_max"=>$p_max,
                    "p_sous"=>$p_max,
                    "fact_index"=>$fact_index,
                    "coef_mult"=>$coef_mult,
                    "p_exp"=>$p_exp,
                    "e_exp"=>$e_exp,
                    "cons_act"=>$cons_act,
                    "cons_react"=>$cons_react,
                    "cos_phi"=>$cons_phi,
                    "pf"=>$pf,
                    "pena"=>$pena,
                    "mnt_redev"=>$mnt_redev,
                    "mnt_energie"=>$mnt_energie,
                    "mnt_total"=>$mnt_total,
                    "mois_concerne"=>$mois_conc,
                    "tva"=>$tva,
                    "mnt_tva"=>$total_tva,
                    "date_p1"=>$date_p1,
                    "date_p2"=>$date_p2,
                    "client"=>$client,
                    "clientId"=>$clients->id_client,
                    "code"=>$code
        
                   );

                $data['titre'] = "Facturation";
                $data['innerdata'] = 'admin/facture/multiple_fact';
                $this->load->view('admin/template', $data);
              

       }
             
    }
```

I want to display the calculated results for each customer in a table :

```
<div class="right_col" role="main">
         
        <div class="x_panel">
           <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Facturation multiple</h2>
                   
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <a href="<?= base_url('cclient/list') ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon-split">
                            <span class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="text text-light">
                                Liste client
                            </span>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="x_content">
                    <form action="<?php echo base_url('cfacturation/save'); ?>" method="post" id="form" class="">
                      <div><?php $this->load->view('_partials/messages.php') ?></div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">


                          <table class="table">
                          <tr>
                            <th>Client</th>
                            <th>Mois</th>
                            <th>Montant facture</th>
                            <th>Energie consommée</th>
                          </tr>

                          <?php foreach($facture as $fact){ ?>

                          <tr>
                          
                          <td><input type="text" readonly value="<?= set_value($fact->designation); ?>" id="mnt_redev" class="form-control" name="mnt_redev" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" readonly value="<?= set_value($fact->mois_concerne); ?>" id="mois" class="form-control" name="mois" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" readonly value="<?= set_value($fact->mnt_total); ?>" id="mnt_total" class="form-control" name="mnt_total" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" readonly value="<?= set_value($fact->mnt_redev'); ?>" id="mnt_redev" class="form-control" name="mnt_redev" /></td>
                         
                         
                          </tr>

                          <?php } ?>
                          </table>
                       
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <hr>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enregistrer</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
                          
                      </div>
                        
                      </div>
                    </form>

                  </div>
            </div>
      
</div>
```

I get this error :

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
> Message: Trying to get property 'designation' of non-object
> Filename: facture/multiple_fact.php
> Line Number: 44

Comment: Evidently, `$fact` is not an object. Judging by what you are passing into the view from your controller, it's probably a string. You're only passing a single associative array to the view (it's the stuff in `$data['facture'] = array(`, by the looks of it), not a list of objects. So if you loop through that, you're looping through each key in the array, and getting out its value. None of those values will be objects, from what I can see in your controller code. Your view seems designed to expect a completely different data structure than what you're actually providing to it.

Comment: how else to provide the data to my view

Comment: Your options are, a) provide data from the controller in a structure which matches the view code's expectations, or b) change the view code to process the structure being provided by the controller. I don't know which one of those would best meet your requirements (your specification, as provided here, is quite vague) or where any other data would be taken from. All I can do is point out the logical flaws in your current attempt.

Comment: Question: When you run this query: `$query = $this->db->get();` do you expect that it will only ever return 1 row of data, or could it return several rows? Because right now, your PHP code assumes it will only return 1 row.

Comment: I browse this result with foreach ($query->result() as $clients)

Comment: Yes, I see that, but then inside it you write something like `$index_act2 = $row->index_actif;`, which just overwrites the same field every time it loops. So in the code after the loop, you'll only ever see one value for that field - whatever value was the last one in the SQL results. I wasn't sure if  that was intentional or not. You have just pointed out some code I had already seen...you didn't actually answer my question!

Comment: your question, I didn't understand it

Comment: You mean this: `do you expect that it will only ever return 1 row of data, or could it return several rows?` I think? It's not a complicated question, I don't know how else to say it. You surely have some idea what you intend the query to return. It's important because you have written your code in such a way that it will only ever process 1 result from the query. If the query returns more than 1 result, the PHP code will ignore all the other results. I don't know if that's what you intended, or not (because you have not provided any sample data, or any clear indication of the expected output)

Comment: it could  return several rows

Comment: Ok then thanks. So that means that any code which you want to be applied to every row, must be within the `foreach ($query->result() as $row){  ... }` area. At the moment you have nothing in there, except for defining some variables, which you then don't use until after the loop ends (which does not make much sense!)